# Filtered HTML adding two <br> tags, not one

Tags: 7

I have a "Filtered HTML" text field and have the convert line breaks to `<br>` & `<p>` tags option turned on in the configuration but when I'm adding content to a "Filtered HTML" field and use Shift + Enter to create a newline within the same paragraph Drupal seems to be adding in two `<br>` tags rather than one, which I'd expect.

For an example the text

```
"I'm having
a great day"
```

gets turned into

```
"I'm having<br><br>
a great day"
```

Is there any way to alter this behaviour to add just one `<br>` tag instead of two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I've found of resolving this is to replace the two `<br />` tags with one using a `str_replace` in the field preprocess function. I've placed an example below.

```
function theme_preprocess_field(&$vars) {
  switch($vars['element']['#field_name']) {
    // When pressing Shift + Enter in WYSIWYG editor to create a new line it outputs two <br /> tags, not one.
    case "field_description":
      $vars["items"][0]["#markup"] = str_replace("<br /><br />", "<br />", $vars["items"][0]["#markup"]);

      break;
  }
}
```